# Find a formula for $card(A)=n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a finite set with $card(A)=n$, define a set 
$${\mathcal{S} }= \{(U,T) \in \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(A)|U \subseteq T\}$$. Find a formula for $card({\mathcal{S} })$ in terms of n and prove it.

I tried to write down $\mathcal{S} $ explicitly when A has a small number of element but didn’t find anything.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: If you add another element to A, how many new pairs (S,T) will you get? That should give you a simple recursive formula for the result.

Comment: Please do not use the same symbol $S$ to denote two different things.

Comment: -1 because you claimed you "tried to write down $\mathcal S$ when $A$ has a small number of element" but didn't tell us what values of $n$ you tried and what you got for $\mathcal S.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $A$ there exists $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of size $k$, and each subset of size $k$ has $2^k$ subsets, so
$$
card(S)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k=(1+2)^n=3^n
$$ 
By binomial theorem.

Comment: And the sum simplifies nicely by the binomial theorem.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Yes, you have reason

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Got it @Gödel

Answer (score 1):

You can also answer it using combinatorics with an element-wise view. The solution is equivalent to finding the number of ways that one can form two subsets $S$ and $T$ of $A$ (with $n$ elements), where $S\subseteq T$. To form such subsets, for any single element $x\in A$ there are three choices:

- $x\notin T, x\notin S$
- $x\in T, x\notin S$
- $x\in T, x\in S$

Since there are total $n$ elements, the number of ways to form subsets $S$ and $T$ would be $3^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\mathcal{S}=\bigcup_{T\in\mathcal{P}(A)}\{(S,T)\mid S\in\mathcal{P}(T)\} $$