# How many pairs of sets $(X,Y)$ exist such that $X \subset Y \subset [n]$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

> Consider $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ an unordered set. How many pairs of sets $(X,Y)$ exist such that $X \subset Y \subset [n]$?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: what have you tried, also is it proper subset?

Comment: For a subset $Y$ then how many $X$ are such that $X \subset Y$ ?

Comment: This is a “problem statement question” and is not well received here: this site is not a homework solving facility. Please show your work and tell where you're stuck at.

Comment: This is not a homework. I think the answer is (n-1)2^n but i am not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a formula for $card(A)=n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702755/find-a-formula-for-carda-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this solves the problem of counting the number of sets $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\subseteq Y \subseteq [n]$, not with strict inequalities.

Suppose we condition on the size of set $Y$, how many subsets of $Y$ are there ? If $|Y|=k$, then there $2^k$ of those, since every element can be in $X$ or be in $X^c$, which create $2$ possibilities for all elements of $Y$. Also there are $n \choose k$ different sets $Y$ such that $|Y|=k$. Hence the answer you seek is given by
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k} 2^k &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k} 2^k1^{n-k}\\
&= 3^n
\end{align*}

By Newton's formula.

---

Seeing this result gives us the intuition that there may be a faster way to get there. Every number $i$ in $[1:n]$ have $3$ possibilities :

- $i\notin Y$
- $i\in Y$ and $i\notin X$
- $i\in X$

This creates $3$ choice for every number in $[1{:}n]$ hence the number of possibilities is $3^n$

---

If you want to have strict $X\subset Y \subset [n]$, then we need to remove from these the case where $Y=[n]$ and each cases where $X=Y$, hence the summation becomes

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n\choose k} (2^k-1) &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n\choose k} 2^k - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n\choose k}\\
&= 3^n-2^n-(2^n-1)\\
&=3^n-2^{n+1}+1
\end{align*}

Comment: I considered that each element has the option of belonging or not to the X set. If |X|=k, therefore there are 2^(n-k) possibilites of different sets for Y. So the number I was looking was Sum[2^k * 2^(n-k),{k,1,n-1}] =(n-1)*2^n. Why is this wrong?

Comment: because the number of sets $X$ of size $k$ is ${n\choose k}$

Comment: The last answer was the one I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: When you calculated the sum using Newtown's formula, shouldn't the expoent be n-1 instead of n?

Comment: What happens here is $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n\choose k} p^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k} p^k-{n\choose n} p^n=(p+1)^n-p^n$